# Visual Studio: Refresh "Find All References" results

Tags: visual-studio

The Find All References tool is very useful, but I often find myself wishing I could refresh the results, such as:

- After changing one of the listed lines such that it no longer references what I did "Find all References" on.
- After adding or removing some lines of code, which messes up the "double-click to go to line" feature of the "Find All References" window.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to refresh the results, but I find this hard to believe. Am I overlooking something or is this really a missing feature?

I'm aware I can go to some place where the method/variable/etc. is used, right-click it, and do "Find All References" again, but that's much more tedious than just hitting a Refresh button.

Comment: There is also a keyboard shortcut. CTRL+K followed by R

Comment: For me that brings up the Object Browser... under my Keyboard settings, it says Ctrl+K, Ctrl+R is assigned to "View.ObjectBrowserGoToSearchCombo". What does yours say?

Comment: Visual Studio Version? Mine 2019 Pro.

Comment: Edit.FindAllReferences (Global)

Comment: Same here. What exactly happens when you hit Ctrl+K, R?

Comment: Open the windows with the references to the method under the caret

Comment: Edit.FindAllReferences just performs a new "Find All References" on whatever the caret is currently on. It doesn't refresh the current results.

Comment: Yes, my comment was addressed to your last line. AFAIK there is no _update the current results_ command, but VS is so huge... perhaps I simply don't know

Comment: Oh I see. Actually the most tedious part of that process is the hunting down an existing usage of the method/variable. If I just replaced one, and the double-click to find isn't working right (because line numbers have changed), it suddenly becomes a much more involved process. Anyway thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After more investigation, this isn't currently possible. However, there's a request for it in the VS community forum. If you think a Refresh for "Find" or "Find All References" would be useful, please vote for the following requests:

- [Add a "refresh" button to "find references" (Shift-F12) window](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/393647/add-a-refresh-button-to-find-references-shift-f12.html)
- [Add a 'Refresh' Button to Find Results tabs](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/589635/add-a-refresh-button-to-find-results-tabs.html)